# How to return two different search results in one in searchkick (ElasticSearch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have these two search

```
foods = Food.search name, fields: [:name], where: {
   or: [
    [{nutritionist_id: nil}, {nutritionist_id: current_nutritionist_id}]
   ]
}, order: {_score: :desc}

recipes = Recipe.search name, fields: [:recipe_name], where: {
   or: [
        [{nutritionist_id: nil}, {nutritionist_id: current_nutritionist_id}]
      ]
 }, order: {_score: :desc}
```

I want that `foods` and `recipes` been returned in the same result. Like merge them, something like above or other better way.

```
return foods + reciples
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this with `Searchkick.search`
Instead of:

```
foods = Food.search name, fields: [:name], where: {
   or: [
    [{nutritionist_id: nil}, {nutritionist_id: current_nutritionist_id}]
   ]
}, order: {_score: :desc}
```

and

```
recipes = Recipe.search name, fields: [:recipe_name], where: {
   or: [
        [{nutritionist_id: nil}, {nutritionist_id: current_nutritionist_id}]
      ]
 }, order: {_score: :desc}
```

I used.

```
result = Searchkick.search(name, index_name: [Food, Recipe], fields: [:name, :recipe_name], 
  where: {
      _or: [ {nutritionist_id: nil}, {nutritionist_id: current_nutritionist_id} ]
  }, order: {_score: :desc})
result
```

This way the Searchkick search in these two models `Food` and `Recipe` and returns the array with both results.